# How to use onClick event to pass the props from child component to parent component React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-props

PopupButtonTesting.js

```
const PopupButtonTesting = ({metaData, items, render}) = {
 const [open,toggle] = useButtonToggle({type: 'button1', open: false})'
 return (
  <>
   <ButtonBase metaData={metaData} onClick={toggle}>
    {open && items.map((m,i) => render(
       {...m.button1, 
       index:i, 
       onClose: toggle, 
       open})
     )}
  </>
 )
}

const ButtonBase = (mataData, onClick) => {
 const {dataField} = metaData
 return (
   <Button onClick={() => onClick('button1')}>
     show button1
   </Button>
| 
   <Button onClick={() => onClick('button2')}>
     show button2
   </Button>
 )
}
```

useButtonToggle.js

```
export default (initToggleState = {type: 'button1', open: false}) => {
  const [toggleState, setState] = useState(initToggleState);
  const toggle =setState(// add some logic here maybe);
  return [toggleState, toggle]
}
```

So `ButtonBase` component is the child component of `PopupButtonTesting` component, so there are two button rendered in this child component. I want to click the button1 and shows the button1 data and open button2 shows the button2 data, so in the `ButtonBase`, I have passed in 'button1' and 'button2' in the onClick, which corresponding the onClick passed into `ButtonBase`, then I want to modify `useButtonToggle` to identify the button type, but I am not sure how should I add in the `useButtonToggle`.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to pass props from child to parent, the best way is calling it via function parameter,

```
const someFunc = (varFromChild) => //do something

<ChildComponent funcToChild={(paramFromChild) => someFunc(paramFromChild) }
```

Then in ChildComponent

```
onClick={() => props.funcToChild(something)}
```